# Scrapy Request with callback not being executed

Tags: python-2.7, callback, scrapy

My spider is running so far so good. Everything works but this bit:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from info.items import InfoItem

class HeiseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "heise"

    start_urls = ['https://www.heise.de/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print ( "Parse" )
        yield scrapy.Request(response.url,callback=self.getSubList)

    def getSubList(self,response):
        item = InfoItem()

        print ( "Sub List: Will it work?" )
        yield(scrapy.Request('https://www.test.de/', callback = self.getScore, dont_filter=True))
        print ( "Should have" )

        yield item

    def getScore(self, response):
        print ( "--------- Get Score ----------")
        print ( response )

        return True
```

The output is:

```
Will it work?
Should have
```

Why is `getScore` not being called? 
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Changed code to a barebone version with the same issue - getScore not being called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just did a test run and it went through all callbacks as expected:

```
...
2017-05-13 12:27:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.heise.de/> (referer: None)
Parse
2017-05-13 12:27:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.heise.de/> (referer: https://www.heise.de/)
Sub List: Will it work?
Should have
2017-05-13 12:27:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.test.de/> (referer: https://www.heise.de/)
--------- Get Score ----------
<200 https://www.test.de/>
2017-05-13 12:27:59 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'bool' in <GET https://www.test.de/>
2017-05-13 12:27:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-05-13 12:27:59 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 693,
...
```

Without any logging output and the settings.py missing it's a bit guessing but it's quite likely that in your settings.py is a `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=True`.

This means scrapy will respect any limitations that are imposed by robots.txt files and https://www.test.de has a robots.txt that disallows crawling.

**So change the ROBOTSTXT line in settings.py to `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False` and it should work.**